# If a string is empty PHP

Tags: php, string

I am trying to create an if-statement to show content if it is not empty. It currently shows the if is empty value.

```
$openHomeStart = '2012-11-10T01:00:00Z';

if(!empty($openHomeStart)){
    echo 'value';
}else{
    foreach ($openHomeTimes as $time){
        $openHomeDetails .= $time;
    }       
}
```

Comment: "Which value" is the "if is empty value"? Because that should echo "value" .. that conditional reads: "if $openHomeState is NOT empty then .."

Comment: Can you just copy the actual code here? You didn't use unquoted 'Time Literal' (for what it might mean), did you?

Comment: `$openHomeTimes` is a string not an `array` you can not loop on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have your condition the wrong way. You have it outputting "value" if $openHomeStart *is not empty*. If you want it to iterate over the value (and having a value is the only way you could iterate over it then you just need to remove the ! from your condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
$openHomeStart = "2012-11-10T01:00:00Z";
if(empty($openHomeStart))
{
    echo 'empty';
} else {
    echo 'not empty';
}
```

Well... Shane said it first ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Already said by pst but those backticks won't give an error but won't set the variable either.

```
<?php
$var = `2012-11-10T01:00:00Z`;

echo $var;
```

result: nothing

Also, assuming you just didn't paste the code for the value of $openHomeTimes, if you just want to iterate over $openHomeTimes if $openHomeStart is empty or echo 'some value' if $openHomeStart is not empty then you have your if statements correct. Just change the backtics to quotes.